# How To Run If And Else Block Of Code Alternatively When Page Refresh C# Web App?

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

I am trying to implement some logics, but for that I have to use logic which I am not getting. How would I run an if condition and else condition alternative time when the page refreshes.

What would be the logic hopes for your suggestions?

my code is below,

```
var activeColor = '#ff0000';
var inactiveColor = '#0000FF';  
var points = [  
   new GLatLng(24.85229, 67.01703),  
   new GLatLng(24.914463, 67.0965958),  
   new GLatLng(24.86588, 67.06089),  
new GLatLng(24.9726753, 67.06638),
new GLatLng(24.840023, 67.24285),
new GLatLng(24.85229, 67.01703)
];  
var polyline = new GPolyline(points, '#ff0000', 5, 0.7);  
    GEvent.addListener(polyline, 'click', function() {
           var color = inactiveColor;
           inactiveColor = activeColor;
           activeColor = color;
           polyline.setStrokeStyle({ color: activeColor }); 
        });   
map.addOverlay(polyline);     
                              }
                            }
function reFresh() {
  location.reload(true) 
}
window.setInterval('reFresh()',20000);
```

How to change poly line color alternatively red and blue when page refresh how can we use if else condition here ??

hopes for your suggestions..

Comment: Your question is not really clear... please show some source code and tell what exactly you want to achieve...

Answer (score 2):

Depending upon your actual usage, either a session variable or a value kept in a control.

Comment: i have use polyline google map i want to change google map polyline color actually red to blue and when page refresh it changer it back to red and so on ... . when page refresh

Comment: var activeColor = '#ff0000';
var inactiveColor = '#0000FF';  
var points = [  
   new GLatLng(24.85229, 67.01703),  
   new GLatLng(24.914463, 67.0965958),  
   new GLatLng(24.86588, 67.06089),  
new GLatLng(24.9726753, 67.06638),
new GLatLng(24.840023, 67.24285),
new GLatLng(24.85229, 67.01703)
];  
  var count=0;
count++;
// Create a new polyline  
var polyline = new GPolyline(points, '#ff0000', 5, 0.7);

Comment: GEvent.addListener(polyline, 'click', function() {
           var color = inactiveColor;
           inactiveColor = activeColor;
           activeColor = color;
           polyline.setStrokeStyle({ color: activeColor }); 
        }); 
map.addOverlay(polyline);